# Extrapolating to non-fluid cells (for Shallow Water Equations), for a shore/beach?

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, advection, extrapolation

> The water height $h$ and 2d velocity field $(u,w)$ are *"extrapolated
>   to non-fluid-cells, i.e., setting $h$ equal to the value in the
>   nearest fluid cell."* [Bridson]

I'm using finite differences.

Looking at the [course notes](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/fluidsimulation/), this extrapolation seems involved: tracking the *zero  level set* surface $\phi$ (using *signed distance* from the surface), then taking its gradient $\nabla \phi$.
It seems to be done for *all* non-fluid cells, not just those adjacent to fluid.

I don't understand why this done (BTW for the 2d SWE case, if the non-fluid cell is lower e.g. the lip of a dam wall, then extrapolating the water height will make large quantities of water appear from nowhere (because the height is so far above the ground).

Is there a simple explanation, and a simpler way to do this?

**EDIT** Two different quantities are being extrapolated, *velocity* and *height*. The *velocity* extrapolation seems to be needed for semi-Lagranian advection. This is where you advect a quantity $q$ by projecting velocities *backwards* over a timestep, to find what value of $q$ was at that location (interpolating between the grid locations where $q$ is stored). The issue is that this back-projection *can* land in a region where there is no $q$... so, you extrapolate the value from the nearest cell that does have $q$ (BTW which is along the normal to the surface).

**EDIT** The other extrapolation, of height $h$, seems to only be used for pressure acceleration. (Its effect seems to be a Neumann BC, zero derivative normal to surface, by making the other side the same as this one...?)  Height $h$ is derived from depth $d$ and bottom $b$, $h=b+d$, and $h$ isn't stored, and doesn't seem to be used again. Although, logically, when $d$ is advected semi-Lagrangianly, it should need extrapolation, the same for any other $q$...

Any good references or articles with a nice precis/lit review, or survey papers?

[Bridson] I'm implementing the SWE from chapter 12 of Bridson's book [*Fluid Simulation for Computer Animation*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Z9eYCgAAQBAJ).

Comment: Shallow water equations are no longer hyperbolic when $h$=0. Therefore boundary value problem becomes ill-posed. One has to do some trickery to avoid that. Check out the survey in the beginning of section 3.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4553.pdf) by Dutykh et al.